# Problem with JavaScript doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, api, text, speech

Hello guys I've met a problem with one JavaScript which doesn't work on mobile but works really well on PC.
Somebody could to give me any advice what I could to change? I'm working on the project free of charged website for people studying Polish and it would be perfect to put it on one page :) thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
    $('a.say').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text= $('input[name="Text"]').val();
    text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    console.log(text);
    var url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + text + "&tl=pl&client=tw-ob";
    $('audio').attr('src', url).get(0).play();
    });
    });
```

```html
HTML
<input type="text" name="Text">
<a href="#" class="say">Check it</a>
<audio src="" class="speech" hidden></audio>
                    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple code like `alert()` . if it don't works your mobile browser doesnt support javascript.

if works your speech system not working

Comment: I put the alert method and alert window works, but still speech doesn't work.. Any ideas how I can to figure out it? :(